# Python Pandas - How to take values in 2nd 3rd rows and add those values to the row that has a max date

Tags: python, pandas

I have below dataset and want to take values from other cell and paste it in the row that has the max date and drop the rest

> Sample data set

```
ID  MILESTONE_NAME    DESC              Completed_Date   DECISION_DATE  SUBMISSION_DATE  EPUBLISHED_DATE
 1  DECISION         Final Decision       6/6/2017        6/6/2017
 1  DECISION         Response Received    6/5/2017        6/5/2017
 2  SUBMIT           Submission           1/1/2019                        1/1/2019
 2  SUBMIT           Re-Submission        1/20/2019                       1/20/2019
 3  EPUBLICATION     E-Published          2/2/2021                                      2/2/2021
 3  SUBMIT           First Submission     12/1/2020                       12/1/2020
```

> Exepected output

```
    ID  MILESTONE_NAME    DESC              Completed_Date  DECISION_DATE  EPUBLICATION_DATE  SUBMISSION_DATE  
     1  DECISION        Final Decision       6/6/2017        6/6/2017     
     2  SUBMIT          Re-Submission        1/20/2019                                        1/20/2019                 
     3  EPUBLICATION    E-Published          12/1/2020                         2/2/2021       12/1/2020
```

Comment: 1/20/2019 is not the max date with SUBMIT MILESTONE_NAME, 12/1/2020 is. Also how are you deciding what row's data is to be added to the output?

Comment: Good question. If the same ID is repeated 3 times then I want to keep the row that has the max completed date and the columns that has decision date, epublication date for the same id should be pasted into the row that has the max completed date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work assuming your date columns have already been converted to dates:

```
d = {k:'max' if v == 'datetime64[ns]' else 'first' for k,v in df.dtypes.items()}

df.groupby('ID',as_index=False).agg(d)
```

Output:

```
   ID  MILESTONE_NAME               DESC Completed_Date DECISION_DATE  SUBMISSION_DATE EPUBLISHED_DATE
0   1  DECISION           Final Decision     2017-06-06    2017-06-06             NaT             NaT
1   2  SUBMIT                 Submission     2019-01-20           NaT      2019-01-20             NaT   
2   3  EPUBLICATION          E-Published     2021-02-02           NaT      2020-12-01      2021-02-02
```